# What should be the default date for a row in a table if the user does not enter in anything?

Tags: date, ms-access, timestamp, ms-access-2013

I have a form in MS Access 2013 that has a date text box. The user may or may not enter in a date here. What value should I write to the table if the user does not entering anything? Assume that I cannot default to the current date, neither on the form nor in the table definition.

Comment: That depends on what date you want the user to enter? Depends totally on your application

Comment: What are the 'business rules' specified for whoever your application is designed for? That should dictate what value is saved for the date field. Personally, I create 'DateAdded' and 'DateChanged' fields in tables. The table design for DateAdded sets that field to =Now(). When someone changes data via a form, the DateChanged field is set to Now(). Either your user or the database designer will dictate what procedure to follow.

Comment: Date() will store only the date part where Now() will store date-time.

Comment: The only two options I have ever uses are _Null_ (for unknown) and _Date_ or _Now_ (for today without/with current time).

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with MS Access but in general I see two possibilities.

- You save a default value that is outside of the range that is valid as user input (depends on your application)
- You save null (see for example [handling null values in MS Access](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-tricks-for-handling-null-values-in-microsoft-access/))

Don't forget to check the value for being null or your default value (depending on what you choose above) before you use it.